# SeekBar.java has error

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have this SeekBar.java :

```
package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
public class SeekBar extends AbsSeekBar {
public interface OnSeekBarChangeListener {
  void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser);


        void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar);


        void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar);


  private OnSeekBarChangeListener mOnSeekBarChangeListener;

    public SeekBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.seekBarStyle);
    }

    public SeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public SeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser, int progress) {
        super.onProgressRefresh(scale, fromUser, progress);

        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, fromUser);
        }
    }


    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener l) {
        mOnSeekBarChangeListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    void onStartTrackingTouch() {
        super.onStartTrackingTouch();
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    void onStopTrackingTouch() {
        super.onStopTrackingTouch();
        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        return SeekBar.class.getName();
    }
}
```

The **Override** lines in onProgressRefresh, onStartTrackingTouch, onStopTrackingTouch give this error :

> Method does not override from its super class.

And this problem causes another error  in my code, how can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeekBar extends AbsSeekBar`

`AbsSeekBar` doesn't have a method named `onProgressRefresh` yet you are using the override annotation.
The `onProgressRefresh` is in `OnSeekBarChangeListener` interface.
I am guessing you forgot to write implents.

`SeekBar extends AbsSeekBar implements OnSeekBarChangeListener`

Answer (score 1):

That error means that its super class does not have those methods(onProgressRefresh, onStartTrackingTouch, onStopTrackingTouch). If you want to override those methods, you shall check the super class. Or you just remove `@Override`

Comment: What do you mean by "check the super class"?